# Dúvida com List C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Após a consulta dos  dados, manter eles em memória e usar o “Contains” para localizar um produto, qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso?
agradeço

Tenho o meu DAL:

```
   public class BuscaProdutosDermaDAL
    {
        private Contexto contexto;


        public List<BuscaProdutosDermaClubeEntity> DadosDermaClube()
        {

            var strQuery = "";
            strQuery += "Usp_Site_BuscaProdutosDermaClub";

            using (contexto = new Contexto())
            {

                var retornoDataReader = contexto.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
                return TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos(retornoDataReader);
            }
        }



        private List<BuscaProdutosDermaClubeEntity> TransformaReaderEmListaObjetos(SqlDataReader reader)
        {
            var retornando = new List<BuscaProdutosDermaClubeEntity>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                BuscaProdutosDermaClubeEntity tabela = new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeEntity()
                {
                    idproduto = reader["PROD_PK_ID"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["PROD_PK_ID"].ToString(),
                    descricaopromocao = reader["PRG_NOME"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["PRG_NOME"].ToString(),
                    descricaoproduto = reader["PROD_DESCRICAO"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : reader["PROD_DESCRICAO"].ToString(),

                };

                retornando.Add(tabela);
            }
            reader.Close();
            return retornando;
        }

    }
```

Buscando os dados:

```
    public void CarregaProdutosDermaClube() {

        var tbuscar = new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL();
        var retorno = tbuscar.DadosDermaClube();
        bool SelecionaProduto = retorno[0].idproduto.Contains("4566");
    }
```

Comment: É webforms ou mvc? Você colocou as duas tags.

Comment: seria webforms, mais eu vou ajustar a pergunta

Answer (score 1):

Cria classe estática e dentro dela uma variável estática do tipo da lista e atribua o retorno para essa variável.
Para acessar basta colocar CLASSE_CRIADA.NOME_DA_VARIAVEL

Classe:

```
public static class Util
{
     public static List<BuscaProdutosDermaClubeEntity> listaProdutos{ get; set; }
}
```

Para utilizar:

```
Util.listaProdutos = new BuscaProdutosDermaClubeDAL().DadosDermaClube();
```